# Ionic Storage not working with multiple Services

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, storage

So when I used Storage in one Service everything worked flawlessly. Now I restructured my Code with a new Ini-Service, where I also want to use Storage and it's not working. It's not setting the properties. So I basically took the logic of the app.component.ts file and put it into the Init-Service, which I call in the ngOnInit()-function on app.component.ts.
I think it has something to do with using Storage in the Ini-Service, which calls my Webservice, which also uses Storage...
Maybe I need to use forwardRef? I tried to use it but it didn't seem to help... (Maybe I used it wrong though...)

ini.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IniService {

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private webservice: WebserviceService
  ) { }
...

  async someFunction() {
     console.log(await this.webservice.doStuff()); // works
     this.storage.set("foo", "someValue"); // doesn't work
     console.log(await this.storage.get("foo")); // doesn't work
  }
}
```

webservice.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebserviceService {

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }
...

  async doStuff() {
     return await this.storage.get("foo"); // works
  }
}
```

Comment: it can be issue with the device storage. Some devices auto delete cache and data when there is low space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive the best practice is to create a central storage service and then inject the storage service into other services that need to interface with the Storage engine.

for example you can create a central storage service like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {
  private _storage: Storage | null = null;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.initStorage();
  }

  async initStorage() {
    const storage = await this.storage.create();
    this._storage = storage;
  }

  public set(key: string, value: any) {
    this._storage?.set(key, value);
  }

  public get(key: string){
    return this._storage.get(key)
  }
}
```

Then, in your webService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebserviceService {

  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService
  ) { }
...

  async doStuff() {
     await this.storageService.set("foo", "somevalue");
     return await this.storageService.get("foo"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a minor usability tweak to this: change `initStorage` method to `private`, then insert `if (!!this._storage) return` before calling "create", and lastly add `await this.initStorage()` at the start of both the "set" and "get" methods... TL;DR: this ensures that the "create" method is called before trying to read or write anything to storage, and you don't need to call it yourself (allowing it to be "private"). for extra safety, you should probably also `await this.platform.ready()` at the top of `initStorage()`.